# how to make a variable work in a function?

Tags: python, function, helper

I want to make a function that store the position, but the position variable in the function goes dark and when run it says:
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'favPlayer2' referenced before assignment
I just start out with function so.. thanks for your help

```
def position():

    if weight > 80 and height > 190:

        position = 'Center'

        print('Your position is: Center')


    if weight > 80 and height < 190:

        print('Your position is: Power Forward or Small Forward')

        favPlayer = str.lower(input("Favorite player in the list (Lebron James, Jayson Tatum): "))

        while favPlayer != 'lebron james' and favPlayer != 'jayson tatum':

            favPlayer = str.lower(input('Please enter the name correctly: '))

    if favPlayer == 'jayson tatum':

        position = 'Small Forward'

        print('Your position is Small Forward')

    elif favPlayer == 'lebron james':

        position = 'Power Forward'

        print('Your position is Power Forward')



    if weight < 80 and height < 190:

        print('Your position is Point Guard or Shooting Guard')

        favPlayer2 = str.lower(input("Favorite player in the list (Chris Paul, Klay Thompson): "))

        while favPlayer2 != 'chris paul' and favPlayer2 != 'klay thompson':

            favPlayer2 = str.lower(input('Please enter the name correctly: '))

    if favPlayer2 == 'chris paul':

        position = 'Point Guard'

        print('Your position is Point Guard')

    if favPlayer2 == 'klay thompson':

        position = 'Shooting Guard'

        print('Your position is Shooting Guard')
position()
```

Comment: first, where are `weight` and `height` defined?

Comment: @Beki it was defined by the user, i used *weight = input("Enter a weight number please (kg): ")* and same with height before the function

Comment: `favPlayer` will be defined only `if weight > 80 and height < 190`. So if weeight and height do not match the condition,  python does not know what to do for `if favPlayer == "jayson tatum"` line

Comment: @Beki I did put a range and integer check so i don't think that's that problem

Comment: Your `favplayer` might not be defined, if the weight is less than 80, the if block won't run and cause UnboundLocalError

Comment: @Fed_Dragon but it did able to ask me if I like jayson tatum or lebron james tho, and I put weight and height inside the function. it only fails when I input jayson tatum

Comment: try put 10kg and anything for height, you will get an error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indent some if blocks to make sure the variable is defined

You can give a global variable, or pass return the value from function. But since you don't have position all the time, I will use a global variable.

```
weight = int(input("Enter your weight: "))
height = int(input("Enter your height: "))

position = None

def get_position():
    global position

    if weight > 80 and height > 190:

        position = 'Center'

        print('Your position is: Center')


    if weight > 80 and height < 190:

        print('Your position is: Power Forward or Small Forward')

        favPlayer = str.lower(input("Favorite player in the list (Lebron James, Jayson Tatum): "))

        while favPlayer != 'lebron james' and favPlayer != 'jayson tatum':

            favPlayer = str.lower(input('Please enter the name correctly: '))

        # indented to make sure 'favPlayer' is defined before the if statement
        if favPlayer == 'jayson tatum':

            position = 'Small Forward'

            print('Your position is Small Forward')

        elif favPlayer == 'lebron james':

            position = 'Power Forward'

            print('Your position is Power Forward')



    if weight < 80 and height < 190:

        print('Your position is Point Guard or Shooting Guard')

        favPlayer2 = str.lower(input("Favorite player in the list (Chris Paul, Klay Thompson): "))

        while favPlayer2 != 'chris paul' and favPlayer2 != 'klay thompson':

            favPlayer2 = str.lower(input('Please enter the name correctly: '))

        if favPlayer2 == 'chris paul':

            position = 'Point Guard'

            print('Your position is Point Guard')

        if favPlayer2 == 'klay thompson':

            position = 'Shooting Guard'

            print('Your position is Shooting Guard')

get_position()
print(position)
```

output:

```
Enter your weight: 10 
Enter your height: 29
Your position is Point Guard or Shooting Guard
Favorite player in the list (Chris Paul, Klay Thompson): Chris Paul
Your position is Point Guard
```

Comment: thanks a lot, but how do I assign Shooting guard into position, because i'll use it later on.

Comment: like I want the function to assign the position into a variable, so I could call it, ie. if position() == Shooting Guard... I don't know if that's posible